# Unable to build android test project with ant

Tags: java, android, ant

I have a sample Android app, created with Eclipse, having one Activity.
I ran this command to build the ant build files for this project:

```
android create project --target 8 --name SampleApp --path ./SampleApp --activity MainActivity --package com.example.sampleapp
```

Running "ant debug" successfully builds the project and creates the apk files:

```
-post-build:

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Now, I want to create an Android Test Project. I run this command:

```
android create test-project -m ../SampleApp -n SampleAppTest -p SampleAppTest
```

This successfully created the SampleAppTest directory containing the build files. I have a single class, src/com/example/sampleapp/MainActivityTest.java:

```
package com.example.sampleapp;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super("com.example.sampleapp", MainActivity.class);
    }

}
```

I want to build this project. In the tutorial found here http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsAnt it says I should be able to do "ant run-tests". Unfortunately this target does not exist:

```
$ ant run-tests
Buildfile: /Users/cmuraru/Work/androidtest/SampleAppTest/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "run-tests" does not exist in the project "SampleAppTest". 

Total time: 0 seconds
```

If I try "ant debug" I receive an error when compiling, stating that the MainActivity class (from SampleApp) can not be found.

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/cmuraru/Work/androidtest/build/test/classes
    [javac] /Users/cmuraru/Work/androidtest/SampleAppTest/src/com/example/sampleapp/MainActivityTest.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class MainActivity
    [javac] public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    [javac]                                                                        ^
    [javac] /Users/cmuraru/Work/androidtest/SampleAppTest/src/com/example/sampleapp/MainActivityTest.java:18: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class MainActivity
    [javac] location: class com.example.sampleapp.MainActivityTest
    [javac]         super("com.example.sampleapp", MainActivity.class);
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/cmuraru/Work/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:705: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/cmuraru/Work/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:718: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

When trying "ant test", it also fails:

```
test:
     [echo] Running tests ...
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.sampleapp.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
     [exec] android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.example.sampleapp.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
     [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:616)
     [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:118)
     [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
     [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
     [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:237)
     [exec]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I missing/doing wrong here? Any help is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I spotted the problem.
I failed to mention that in ant.properties, I've changed the out.dir location to "../build". Because of this, the compiler did not know where to get the class files of the SampleApp when building the SampleAppTest. So one solution is to delete the out.dir entry in ant.properties, but I did not want that. I had to find a way to tell the compiler where to get these classes. The solutions I found was to override the "-compile" target in build.xml like so:

```
<property name="SampleApp.build.location" value="../build"/>
    <target name="-compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
        <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
            <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
            <path id="project.javac.classpath">
                <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
                <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
            </path>
            <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                    source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
                    debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
                    destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                    bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
                    verbose="${verbose}"
                    classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
                    fork="${need.javac.fork}">
                <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
                <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
                <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
                <classpath>
                    <!-- steff: we changed one line here !-->
                    <fileset dir="${SampleApp.build.location}/classes" includes="*"/>
                </classpath>
            </javac>

            <!-- if the project is instrumented, intrument the classes -->
            <if condition="${build.is.instrumented}">
                <then>
                    <echo level="info">Instrumenting classes from ${out.absolute.dir}/classes...</echo>

                    <!-- build the filter to remove R, Manifest, BuildConfig -->
                    <getemmafilter
                            appPackage="${project.app.package}"
                            libraryPackagesRefId="project.library.packages"
                            filterOut="emma.default.filter"/>

                    <!-- define where the .em file is going. This may have been
                         setup already if this is a library -->
                    <property name="emma.coverage.absolute.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/coverage.em" />

                    <!-- It only instruments class files, not any external libs -->
                    <emma enabled="true">
                        <instr verbosity="${verbosity}"
                               mode="overwrite"
                               instrpath="${out.absolute.dir}/classes"
                               outdir="${out.absolute.dir}/classes"
                               metadatafile="${emma.coverage.absolute.file}">
                            <filter excludes="${emma.default.filter}" />
                            <filter value="${emma.filter}" />
                        </instr>
                    </emma>
                </then>
            </if>

            <!-- if the project is a library then we generate a jar file -->
            <if condition="${project.is.library}">
                <then>
                    <echo level="info">Creating library output jar file...</echo>
                    <property name="out.library.jar.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/classes.jar" />
                    <if>
                        <condition>
                            <length string="${android.package.excludes}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0" />
                        </condition>
                        <then>
                            <echo level="info">Custom jar packaging exclusion: ${android.package.excludes}</echo>
                        </then>
                    </if>

                    <propertybyreplace name="project.app.package.path" input="${project.app.package}" replace="." with="/" />

                    <jar destfile="${out.library.jar.file}">
                        <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                                includes="**/*.class"
                                excludes="${project.app.package.path}/R.class ${project.app.package.path}/R$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/BuildConfig.class"/>
                        <fileset dir="${source.absolute.dir}" excludes="**/*.java ${android.package.excludes}" />
                    </jar>
                </then>
            </if>

        </do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
    </target>
```

Comment: Need to wait 2 days in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually updating ant.properties there is a way to do it.
from command line, Run following command:

```
android update test-project -m <project path> -p <test project path>
```

After running this command, you can run ant debug directly from test project.
Note: If it gives JUnit related errors, please add Junit jar file in the test project libs folder.