# Running make command error for linphone-android

Tags: java

I am trying to run a make command in a Linux(REDHAT 7) box. I have navigated through all the posts but I am stuck with the following error:

Make: *** [generate-apk] Error 1

It comes, from where I could tell:

/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

The line in the xml that is having the issue is the following fork=”${need.javac.fork}”

I have tested all the java paths - they are okay as well, ant is running fine, everything seems to be installed correctly and I have run out of ideas.

My settings
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-1.b14.el7_2.x86_64

Comment: No idea, but possible this post has suggestions..[build ant error Compile failed; at line fork=“${need.javac.fork}”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26356505/1248974)

Comment: thanks for the response.

Comment: Sure, glad to try, I'm just google-searching your error messages until others offer their ideas, maybe this other question relates [Unable to build android test project with ant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13582445/1248974)